# What is the best / most used / recommended C++ non-blocking networking library for low-latency / real-time development?

Tags: programming

I'm coming from Java and there we use the EPoll selector implementation that comes with the JDK for non-blocking / asynchronous networking TCP and UDP development. Therefore you don't have to make choices.

But when it comes to C++ there are dozens of options to choose from according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library

I don't have experience with C++ so I don't know. Which one should I pick for low-latency, asynchronous, non-blocking, real-time, selector style network programming? Does C++ even have a standard non-blocking network library or are they all external / independent?

Comment: Hello, if any of these answers fulfill what you were looking for please mark it as accepted. If not, edit the question to allows us to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

networking will be available as standard only in c++17, currently boost is an option if you want to abstract the operational system features ( epool, kqueue, io completion ), low latency or realtime try dpdk to bypass operational system kernel.

Comment: Thanks! But c++17 is coming only in 2017 the earliest, right? Can you explain the difference between [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) and [Asio](http://think-async.com/Asio/)?

Comment: its the same thing, they explain here [think-async](http://think-async.com/Asio/AsioAndBoostAsio) IMO the main difference is the possibility to use the library without need of boost, some developers doesnt like it :D

Answer (score 3):

Take a look on [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/). This is really good library.

Another link I consider you should to check is [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html). You may find it a bit outdated and hard to understand from first try but concept is very close to MINA and NIO.

Comment: forgot to mention those, thanks for remind ;)